# Embedding Python 3.3

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, linker, embedding

I try to embed Python 3.3, as described [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/embedding.html).

I'm on MacOS 10.8 which has Python 2.7 so I downloaded binary distribution of version 3.3 from python.org. From it I got all the headers and "Python" which I renamed to "python33" so it wont collide with installed "Python" lib. I put everything into a folder:

embed.c /include python33

"file python33" says:

```
python33 (for architecture i386):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
python33 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

and embed.c is:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("print 'test'\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

But when I do "gcc embed.c -I./include -L. -lpython33" it breaks with:

```
ld: library not found for -lpython33
```

Please, does anyone know how to make it compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and formost, the library has to be named in the form of 'libxxx.so', then the linker will find it with '-L. -lxxx'.

Even then, the resulting executable wont work as one has to copy/create not just the library but the whole framework.

More here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Feb/msg00522.html

Answer (score 0):

Run `python3.3-config --cflags` and you'll get the needed cflags for your system. For ldflags, the command is `python3.3-config --ldflags`

Comment: ./python3.3-config --> -bash: ./python3.3-config: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3m: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: On my system (OS X 10.8.2 with python 3.3 from official installer) it's working like a charm. My output is 
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64
-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lpython3.3m

Comment: I don't have Python 3.3 installed - I just downloaded it and extracted the main lib. When I do `gcc embed.c -I./include -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -L. -lpython33` it still says "ld: library not found for -lpython33"

Comment: Obviously. It would be a good idea to install it before trying to use it.

Comment: I just want to embed it and bundle the needed libs with the executable. Do I have to **install** Python 3.3? I thought that as it is possible to run a program which brings all its dependencies along without actually installing all its libs, it should be possible just to copy the needed libs out of pre-compiled Python and bundle those with the executable?

Comment: You install the lib for compiling.