# Using dynamic library

Tags: compilation, linker, dynamic-library

When I would like to compile a program which uses a dynamic library, do I have to install (i.e. copy to a specific place, say, /usr/share/lib) this library? Or is it ok, if I put this library to any place somewhere and later during linking I point the linker to it, e.g. '-L ./thelibfolder'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I have to install (i.e. copy to a specific place, say, /usr/share/lib) this library?

No.

For a UNIX shared library, you need to arrange for two things:

- You have to make the library known to the static linker, while linking main executable. Usually this is achieved by adding `-L/path/to/directory -lfoo` link flags to the link line.
- You have to make runtime loader search `/path/to/directory` as well. This is system-specific. On many systems, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable achieves the desired  result, though this is usually not the preferred method. Another method is to encode this path into the application itself, e.g. on Linux one would add `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/directory` to the application link line.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The problem I have is that the linker cannot find a library - I asked about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007309/embedding-python-3-3, then I wanted to confirm whether I really need to install Python 3.3. I tried both options you mention (`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="." gcc embed.c -I./include -L. -lpython33` and `gcc embed.c -I./include -rpath=. -L. -lpython33` - gcc does not recognize the `-Wl` switch) but it still does not work. Please, do you perhaps know why it fails to link?